# Can i add multiple claim provider in my relying party ? I want to establish SSO with more than one client

Tags: wif, adfs2.0

I have web application which is my relying party and I want to implement SSO for more than one client.

Add STS reference will add claim info in my web application but can i add multiple STS reference for multiple clients/claim providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to do this is to add other clients as Claims Providers in ADFS.

Then when you connect, ADFS will show a "Home Realm Discovery" screen which will allow the user to select the provider of choice.

Comment: So for each Claim provider, do I need to Add "STS Reference" for each claim provider metadata in my web application?

Comment: No - just the one reference to ADFS. In the ADFS wizard, add the other Claims Providers - much the same process as adding a RP.

Comment: Thank you nzpcmad. Like in form authentication we can skip some pages  by allowing user without authentication. Can I achieve same after implementing ADFS 2.0 in my web application as my web.config with Form authentication and login page will be on adfs website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664156/how-to-allow-anonymous-access-to-a-single-folder-on-an-adfs-managed-site Pretty much standard ASP.NET as to which pages are which.

Answer (score 0):

Each relying party should only ever know about 1 STS.  However if you want to support multiple Logins/STS's you can do this by making your first STS - an STS but also a Relying party. So when your relying party redirects back to the first STS, the first STS then delegates the responsibility for creating the token back to the second STS.  The second STS issues a token to the first STS. The first STS takes this token and sets its claimsprincipal with it, then it isssues a token using this identity to the original Relying party.
Like so:
[image]