# How to allow anonymous access to a single folder on an ADFS managed site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, adfs

Asp.net site deployed to IIS7; the site is protected by ADFS. I have the need to allow anonymous access to a single folder on the site.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual.

If this is a WebForms application, you create a local `web.config` and add an authorization section configured for anonymous access.

If this is a MVC app, you put the `AllowAnonymous` on your controller.

The WS Federation Authentication module shouldn't redirect to ADFS.

Btw. The site is not "protected by ADFS". The ADFS is just an external authentication source, the Security Token Service, in wsfed terms. The site is most probably protected by the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule module` that is commonly used for initializing wsfed handshake and consuming SAML tokens.

Comment: Do you mean add another web.config in the folder that I want to allow anonymous access to? In the main config, there is a location tag as shown below; should I just put another location tag with the folder in question?<location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
 <pages validateRequest="false" />

    </system.web>
  </location>

Comment: another location is better, not a new web.config. WIF doesn't like extra web.config.